# R file generated in a wrong project

Tags: android

I divided my project in three to be possible to generate a Paid and free apps and three third one have the common code, for exemple:

- FreeAppProject
- PaidAppProject
- CommonSource (Android Library Project)

But for now I have just the Paid and CoomonSource projects.

I started doing the changed slowly and test at each change (when I moved a class to the coomon project I tested to see if every think was working).

everything goes fine until I moved the class (the MainActivity), when I moved it, the R file of the Common Project started to be generated on the Paid Project.

My idea is create a SplashScreen that launch the MainActivity in the  Common Project.